# Нет звука в windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Нет звука в windows 8, он как бы есть, в микшере показывает, что музыка играет, но на наушники вывести не могу ![img1][1]![img2][2][1]:http://i.imgur.com/onhRS.png[2]:http://i.imgur.com/rISvn.png

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее всего нужно утилиту для аудио пытать. Ты наверное наушники спереди ПК вставляешь.

Comment: Имеется такая же проблема. Сзади воткнуты колонки. Без драйверов реалтека, кстати, если втыкать наушники спереди, то они сразу заменяли колонки. С реалтеком похоже вообще не работает. Было бы интересно знать, как это настраивается.

Answer (score 0):

в настройках выбери устройство аудио вывода пуск--- панель управления----- Звук

оффтопзы Модератор Iranda хватит редактировать мои ответы...Откровенно уже надоело :[